# Remove div having particular name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From the code underneath, I want to remove the previous instances of codemirror, that is both "hello" and "hii" before I can add another instance.
The jQuery is not working.

Also, if I `console.log($('#source').hasClass('.CodeMirror.cm-s-default'));` it always shows me false, that is it can't find the classnames.

How can I do this?

If this is my html code:

```
<div class = "source" id="source" name="source">
  <div class="result" id="result">
  <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">hello</div>
  <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">hii</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript, jquery is:

```
var first = document.getElementById("source").getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror cm-s-default");
var len1 = first.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    if(first[i].className == "CodeMirror cm-s-default") {
        first[i].parentNode.removeChild(first[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you selected it by the class name, why are you checking it?

Comment: No periods when using `.hasClass()`. And `.hasClass()` isn't the same as `.find()`

Comment: You have jQuery loaded and you're writing all that longhand JavaScript? Is there something we need to know?

Answer (score 4):

you can do that to remove those elements contain `.CodeMirror` as a `class`:

**javascript:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".CodeMirror").forEach(el => el.remove());
```

```html
<div class="source" id="source" name="source">
  <div class="result" id="result">
    <div class="test">Not to remove</div>
    <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">hello</div>
    <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">hii</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't knew about the native `remove()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe simply like this?

```
$(function() {
  $(".CodeMirror").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` can done like this:

```js
$(".CodeMirror:contains('hello'), .CodeMirror:contains('hii')").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="source" id="source" name="source">
  <div class="result" id="result">
    <div class="test">Not to remove</div>
    <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">hello</div>
    <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">hii</div>
  </div>
</div>
```